# scalar product for $\mathbb Q$-vector space in $\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

In the texbooks I have for linear algebra, the scalar products are only introduced for $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ vector spaces, that lead me to following question:

$W:=span(1,\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb C$ is a two dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space in $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$.

$V:=span(1,\sqrt{2},i) \subset \mathbb C$ is a three dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space in $\mathbb C$.

> Is there a "useful" scalarproduct on $V$ or $W$ as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces?

Comment: The idea of a [positive definite quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_quadratic_form) makes sense over any ordered field. In your examples, the scalar product that takes the given basis elements as an orthonormal basis could well be "useful". I don't see that it is much help with the question you link to, since that question seems to be based on an incorrect assumption about compact subspaces of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Seconding what Rob Arthan says about the linked question. The usual recipe gives a scalar product (and a norm) on any finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$, but $\Bbb{R}$ has uncountable dimension. Also, methods number theory are applied in the study of (positive definite) quadratic forms on finite dimensional spaces over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: For posterity, the link that has been removed from the question and is referred to in the comments is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965688/norms-on-mathbbr-seen-as-a-mathbbq-vector-space. Negative kudos to the OP for removing the link.

Comment: @RobArthan I removed it because people pointed out, that it is not useful for this question anyway, just a distraction. If you think it should be there again, please just edit the question instead.

Comment: @flawr: don't worry: it was less than a nanogram of negative kudos. It just can be a minor irritant if changes to a question stop the discussion in comments making sense.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ of infinite uncountable dimension. 
For any subspace of **finite dimension** of these spaces we can define a scalar product such that a given basis of this subspace is orthogonal.

E.g., for your $V=span\{1,\sqrt{2},i\}$, any vector  $v \in V$ can be expressed as a linear combination $ v=v_1+v_2\sqrt{2}+v_3i$, with $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in Q$ and we can define the scalar product of two vectors $v,u$ as:
$$
\langle v,u\rangle=v_1u_1+v_2u_2+v_3u_3
$$

Clearly, for a subspace of infinite ( possibly uncountable) dimension, this definition is not useful.